# Can I use the img tag on JavaScript to display my image stored in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I'm having trouble on displaying my image on HTML table. The image is stored in MongoDB. Can I use the `<img>` tag on JavaScript to display my image? Or is there another way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>E-commerce Website</title>
        <script>  
            function loadBasket(){
                var basketArray;
                var tableBody;
                var tableHeader = "<tr><th>Product Image</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n";
                for(var i=0; i<basketArray.length; ++i){
                    tableBody += "<tr><td>" + "<img class='categories_img' src='"basketArray[i].image"'>" + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].name + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].price + "</td></tr>";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body onload="loadBasket()"> 
        <table id="basket_list"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What console errors are you getting? Seems like you're using the img tag correctly.

Comment: There's no error on my console. It just doesn't show my image

Comment: `basketArray` is `undefined`, how do you expect to loop through it?

Comment: Because you have no elements in `basketArray`

Comment: As Tyr said, you're setting basketArray as an empty variable and there is nothing in it.

Comment: The data is stored in MongoDB

Comment: If I were you I'd try using a `<canvas>` element instead; loading the image using a dummy image element (`var img = document.createElement('image'); img.src = url;`) and then drawing it in the Canvas (`img.onLoad = function() { canvas.drawImage(img); }`). Do not forget to set the Canvas' width and height to the Image's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing concatenation operator in your image file name part. You need to change that line to following:

```
tableBody += "<tr><td>" + "<img class='categories_img' src='"+basketArray[i].image+"'>" + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].name + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].price + "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few things:

1. You don't insert your html to the table `<table id="basket_list"></table>`
2. `basketArray` is empty.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>E-commerce Website</title>
  <script>
    function loadBasket() {
      var basketArray = [{
        image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTem9.jpg?s=48&g=1",
        name: "test",
        price: "10"
      }];
      var tableBody = "";
      var tableHeader = "<tr><th>Product Image</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>\n";
      for (var i = 0; i < basketArray.length; ++i) {
        tableBody += "<tr><td>" + "<img class='categories_img' src='" + basketArray[i].image + "'>" + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].name + "</td><td>" + basketArray[i].price + "</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById('basket_list').innerHTML = tableHeader + tableBody;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadBasket()">
  <table id="basket_list"></table>

</body>

</html>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/pLOjVX)